# PDF reader that refreshes at updates and stays put

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, latex, productivity

I am looking for a pdf reader which refreshes when the pdf is updated, **while staying (roughly) at the same page it was before the refresh**.

Adobe and Foxit don't refresh. Preview does refresh, but gets you back to the first page after every refresh.

**The reason for all this:** I am using Texstudio to edit LaTex files. TexStudio has an internal pdf viewer which does exactly what I want (refreshing when I recompile the pdf, and staying roughly at the same position in the pdf). But Texstudio only allows you to open a *single* pdf viewer window. I would want to open several to be able to look at the pdf output in different places at the same time (it would significantly improve my productivity).

(OS X El Capitan)

Comment: Closely related and possible duplicate question  [Reopen PDF in Preview on the same page when modified externally](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167917/reopen-pdf-in-preview-on-the-same-page-when-modified-externally?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks @Graham Miln, missed that one when I searched before posting. See my answer below based on the question you point at, and feel free to close my question if needed.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden: You can set your own answer as "accepted" by clicking the 'tick' mark which is good practice if your answer does completely solve your problem.

Comment: Good to hear the link helped. I believe you can mark your answer as the solution or delete the question if you prefer.

Comment: Will do. Have to wait two days though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in a comment by Jonathan Schuster to the question [Reopen PDF in Preview on the same page when modified externally](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167917/reopen-pdf-in-preview-on-the-same-page-when-modified-externally?rq=1) that Graham Miln pointed at.

In his comment, Jonathan wrote

> For what it's worth, I've found Skim to be a good viewer that doesn't
>   have this issue. Just make sure to check "Check for file changes" in
>   the Sync section of Preferences.

which neatly answers my question.